# Return Last Matching Non-Blank Value formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to return the Matching-Last Non-Blank value via the formula below:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($D$7:$M$7=$A9),$D8:$M8)
```

However, the formula doesn't ignore the blank cells.

In the sample below;

- 2nd formula for Red should return 5-Jun
- 3rd formula for Red should return 12 Jan

[image: SO-Excel-Question]

Lastly, I don't want to utilize VBA or array formulas.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: @Harun24hr Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2301)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another parameter to ignore blanks. Try-

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(($D$7:$M$7=$A8)*($D8:$M8<>"")),$D8:$M8)
```

If you are ***Microsoft-365*** then could try-

```
=TAKE(FILTER(G8:M8,($G$7:$M$7=A8)*(G8:M8<>"")),,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you both of them work perfectly! I tried to ignore the blanks on the first formula yesterday. But forgot to put both of the criteria in the parenthesis.